# Duration from Each Hour in 24 hours work

Tags: vba

I have a a MS access table (MasterLogs)with structure as Date, UserName, Position, loginTime, logoutTime.(Login and logout field type is date&time)
I want to extract data from this table to another table (PositionHrs)where the columns are

```
Date
Username
Position
0000-0059
0100-0159
0200-0259 
...
until 2300-2359 (which are basically like time duration).
```

In the Masterlogs table, the records are like 01-Aug-17, Username, position and there will be login logout times (eg:login 01-Aug-17 00:05 and logout time 01-Aug-17 02:45)

I am looking for a VBA code which can read the records in masterlogs and split the minutes of duration to corresponding column in the positionHrs table.
So that table should have a record for the username in 0000-0059 column with a value of 00:54 (54 minutes duration during 0000 to 0059 time and in the 0100-0159 column 01:00 and in the 0200-0259 column the remaining duration 00:45
Hope I have explained well.

Can anyone please help me to fix this ?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: I did not know how to post as another entry, that is why I put it as answr

Comment: Thank you and please let me know my earlier post will help you to have a better understanding. Else I will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding braX. The below code add a record with duration for each person in the corresponding hour. if the person has continuous duration in the next hours it doesn't add those duration to corresponding hour columns.

```
Sub HourlyDuration()
```

Dim rs1 As Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MasterLogs")
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("PositionHrs")

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF
```

'below for adding minutes in rs2![0000-0059] "hour1"

```
    If Format(rs1![On], "hh:nn") >= #12:00:00 AM# And Format(rs1![On], "hh:nn") <= #12:59:59 AM# Then

        Dim St As String

        St =  Format(TimeValue("01:00:00") - TimeValue(RoundTime(rs1!On, 60)), "hh:nn")
```

'roundtime is a function to round time to the next minute (time field is dd-mmm-yy hh:nn:ss)

```
        rs2.AddNew
        rs2![Date] = rs1![Date]
        rs2![0000-0059] = St 
        rs2!Position = rs1!Position
       ' rs2!Staff = rs1!Staff
        rs2.Update
    End If
```

'for rs2![0100-0159]  "hour2"

If Format(rs1![On], "hh:nn") >= #1:00:00 AM# And Format(rs1![On], "hh:nn") <= #1:59:59 AM# Then

```
        Dim st1 As String

        st1 = Format(TimeValue("02:00:00") - TimeValue(RoundTime(rs1!On, 60)), "hh:nn")

       rs2.AddNew
        rs2![Date] = rs1![Date]
        rs2![0100-0159] = st1 
        rs2!Position = rs1!Position
        'rs2!Staff = rs1!Staff
        rs2.Update
    End If
```

' same conditions repeated for all hours, and then

```
rs1.MoveNext

Loop


MsgBox ("Finished")


rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
```

rs2.Close
  Set rs2 = Nothing
End sub